# Alter All TinyInt(1) Columns In Database to Not Null Default 0

Tags: mysql

I have a database, and I need to alter every single

```
tinyint(1) default null
```

column (and incidentally, every value in those columns set to null) in every single table in that database to:

```
tinyint(1) not null default 0
```

as soon as possible.

What is the fastest / most efficient way to achieve this, (programmatically or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query `information_schema.COLUMNS` view for a list of tables/columns, then use your programming language of choice to loop through the results and perform `ALTER TABLE` queries.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourDatabase'
AND COLUMN_TYPE = 'tinyint(1)'
```

Comment: I was hoping for like a handy one-liner in Mysql itself, but yeah, this didn't take that much longer.