# Replace DEFAULT from NULL to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I added several columns(100+) with attribute `TINYINT(1)` and default value `NULL` but problem is that default value must to `0`.

**Is there any way i can do it through query by detecting the fields `TINYINT(1)` and then altering the table ??**

Please help me.

Comment: export whole script to .sql file and find tinyint(1) column and replace design as default 0

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Alter All TinyInt(1) Columns In Database to Not Null Default 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135716/alter-all-tinyint1-columns-in-database-to-not-null-default-0?rq=1), although Guillaume's answer below is more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a query to find those columns in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` which is a bunch of views, automatically maintained by the server.

Try this:

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT * FROM `COLUMNS`
WHERE COLUMN_TYPE = 'tinyint(1)'
```

You can add a filter on the database, or the table. Then, you can create queries directly with this view:

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_SCHEMA, ".", TABLE_NAME, " MODIFY ", COLUMN_NAME, " tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0") AS q
FROM `COLUMNS`
WHERE COLUMN_TYPE = 'tinyint(1)'
```

That would generate queries like: `ALTER TABLE schema.table MODIFY column tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0`, which is what you need to execute to change default value.